# Daily statistic in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for a way to save daily data in my db. For example, there's a possibility to make a donation on my site (like kickstarter or sth). The cost of every donation is stored in a money attribute (donation.money). I would like to make a daily statistic of donations like this (sums up every donation in one day): 3rd of July - 50$, 5th of July - 100$.

 Could someone tell me how to do it? Do I need to make another attribute to sort it by days?
I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Assuming you store timestamps with your donations (`created_at` field), it's a simple SQL query at worst. `SELECT DATE(created_at) day, sum(amount) FROM donations group by day` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add anything, try this:

```
Donation.select("date(created_at) as donations_date, sum(money) as total_amount")
        .group("date(created_at)")
        .map { |r| puts "#{r.donations_date} - #{r.total_amount}" }
```

For more information about grouping, [check guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group).

Comment: Thank you, sir. It works perfectly in console, but in my view I receive only [nil]. What can be a problem?

Comment: @jestemkarol you are welcome. It depends on what you do in your code. Usually you want to create an instance variable to show in view. You can, for example create it like this:
`@statistic = ... .map { |r| { r.donations_date => r.total_amount } }`, so your `@statistic` will hold an array of hashes you can then display.

Comment: you probably tried to output results of query with `.group`, but you can't call `.donations_date` or `.total_amount` on `Donation` objects since they just don't have these fields.

Comment: @rustam-a-gasanov Thank you one more time. I've got only one question left - If I want to show all the dates this month (1-31 days) even if there wasn't any activity (f.e 1 July - 0$, 2 July  - 0$, 3 July 50$) - what exactly I need to add to this code?

Comment: @jestemkarol once again I don't know what you're trying to achieve and your current code. But if you need to show for example current month, you can generate array with hashes which will include all dates in current month and zeros as values, then merge this array with results from database query to fill values.